# Actor-model library, framework, or language written in C?

Tags: c, erlang, actor

The Actor-model was defined in a 1973 paper by Carl Hewitt, but has been popularized by the Erlang language. I believe the parts of Erlang that aren't self-hosted (written in Erlang) are written in C; BEAM and HiPE are written mostly in C. What are some alternative Actor-model implementations (languages, frameworks, or libraries) that are written in C?

Comment: Why not just read the Wikipedia article, lots of links to implementations: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_model#Actor_libraries_and_frameworks

Comment: `@Hans Passant:` Where do you see a C implementation in that list?

Comment: You might want to take a look at this (Erlang-style Concurrency for Other Languages): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22187/erlang-style-concurrency-for-other-languages

Answer (score 2):

There is [libactor](http://code.google.com/p/libactor/) which is a GPLv2 library implementing the actor model in a single process using pthreads.

Answer (score 1):

Consider [libdispatch](http://libdispatch.macosforge.org/).